# How do you know what inter-molecular interactions are present?

Tags: intermolecular-forces

I'm studying for a chem exam and there are often questions of this form: What kind of inter-molecular interactions are important in (insert compound here). Then the possible answers are any combination of dipole-dipole, hydrogen bonding, and dispersion force.
My question is: When ever a molecule has hydrogen bonding does that mean there is also dipole-dipole?

How do you tell if a molecule has a dipole, for instance CH3COOH,  has one but how do you know?

Comment: Look at the electronegativities of the neighbouring atoms. If an atom has a stronger electronegativity than a neighbouring one, it will draw some of its charge, and there will exist a dipole moment. Be careful however in molecules where the charge may be drawn equally, such as in symmetric molecules. These molecules won't necessarily have a net dipole moment.